# url with question mark

Tags: php, forms

This is my php code in `index.php`

```
echo "<form name=\"form\" method=\"post\" action=\"?i=$link\">";
```

It works correctly. The new page url is `http://myurl/myfolder/index.php?i=link`, but I would like to display `http://myurl/myfolder/?i=link`.

How can I do it? Some apache settings maybe?

edit: I hardcoded the url like suggested by Awlad Liton, with the drawback that now I can't move it to another folder. It works fine, but it would be better if I could move it.

edit: done, correct answer from nl-x

Comment: set `action+"http://myurl/?i=link"`

Comment: @izabera have you seen my edited answer?, it isn't hardcoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED because OP was edited:**

Then use `./` in front of your `?`

```
echo "<form name=\"form\" method=\"post\" action=\"./?i=$link\">";
                                                   ^^
```

Comment: sorry, it needs to go to `http://myurl/myfolder/?i=$link` and this way it goes to `http://myurl/?i=$link`.

Answer (score 2):

Just open your page with form as `http://myurl/`, not as `http://myurl/index.php`.
That's all.

Comment: no, it's the return page from a form. i know i can open it this way but this page is loaded automatically.